# Filtering product collection producing incorrect behaviour with flat catalog enabled in admin

Tags: php, product-collection, flat-catalog, magento1.9.2.3

I am using the below code for get most-viewed product in my store front:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'price', 'small_image'])
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

$products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
$this->setProductCollection($products);
```

It's working fine when *"Use Flat Catalog Product"* is set to no.
But when I set *"Use Flat Catalog Product"* to yes, `product name`, `price` and `small_image` attribute not get in collection.

Please help